# OpenCV/C++-Segmentation fault: 11 after mat multiplication

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, segmentation-fault, svd

I am a newbie to OpenCV and am trying to duplicate a code from Matlab to C++
and have the Segmentation fault: 11 when I do the matrix multiplication.
I found that it maybe caused by the `trans*U` in my C++ code.
The size of `trans` is 16032768x3 (row x col) and `U` is 3x3, so I am pretty sure that can be multiplied.

Here is the link of my photos:
[Photos](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_6q4y47ZwRg48sZboJ6OjYXmDL997K46?usp=sharing)

Hope someone can help me solve my problem, thanks!!

Here is my C++ code:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>  

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //import image
    Mat_<double> img1, img2, img3;
    img1 = imread("S1.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    img2 = imread("S2.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    img3 = imread("S3.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    
    //Push all the image it to one matrix for SVDecomp
    Mat_<double> svd_use;
    svd_use.push_back(img1.reshape(0,1));
    svd_use.push_back(img2.reshape(0,1));
    svd_use.push_back(img3.reshape(0,1));
    
    
    Mat_<double> source, trans, B, W, U, VT;
    trans = svd_use.t();
    source = svd_use*trans;
    SVDecomp(source, W, U, VT);
    
    //To make sure the value is the same as matlab
    W = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << W[0][0], 0, 0, 0, W[1][0], 0, 0, 0,W[2][0]);
    U = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << -U[0][0], -U[0][1], U[0][2] , -U[1][0], -U[1][1], U[1][2], -U[2][0], -U[2][1], U[2][2]); 
    B = trans*U;//<---this part causes the  Segmentation fault: 11

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Matlab code

```matlab
%Import images
source_img1 = rgb2gray(imread('S1.JPG'));
source_img2 = rgb2gray(imread('S2.JPG'));
source_img3 = rgb2gray(imread('S3.JPG'));

%Vectorize images
img_vector1 = source_img1(:);
img_vector2 = source_img2(:);
img_vector3 = source_img3(:);


%Calculate SVD
t = double([img_vector1'; img_vector2'; img_vector3']);
[U,S,V] = svd(t*t');
B = t'*V*S^(-1/2);
```

Also, I have question the power of matrix: in Matlab I could directly calculate the `S^(1/2)`,
is there any way to do the same thing in OpenCV?

Comment: Are you sure `trans` is of the size you think it is? Did you examine its sizes in the debugger?

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo: Thanks for helping me! I do use the `code` to check the size of the matrix. The result is that trans width is 3 and height is 16032768. The U is 3 by 3, so I am pretty sure they could be multiply. I also found that if I directly use svd_use.t() to multiply U instead of using trans, it will not cause the seg problem...it's really tricky